# Scroll a div infinity in a circle

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hi I would like to scroll a div infinity in a cirlce (horizontal). When I scroll the div on right and it comes to the end, it should'nt stop, it should start with the first item and go around. At the moment I can only scroll from left to right and back. It stops by the last item. This is my code:

```js
$(".arrowLeft").click(function(){
   var e = $('.myList');
    var scrollLength = 20;
 e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() - scrollLength);
});

$(".arrowRight").click(function(){
   var e = $('.myList');
    var scrollLength = 20;
 e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() + scrollLength);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.myList {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.arrows {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.listItems {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="arrows arrowLeft">&larr;</div>
    
      <div class="myList">
        <div class="listItem">Item 1</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 2</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 3</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 4</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 5</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="arrows arrowRight">&rarr;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to scroll infinitiy when I click on the arrows left and right.

Here an example with a drawn picture for the right arrow:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
$(".arrowLeft").click(function() {
  var e = $('.myList');
  var scrollLength = 20;
  e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() - scrollLength);
  if (e.scrollLeft() == 0) {
    $('.listItem').last().insertBefore($('.listItem').first());
    e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() - scrollLength);
  }
});


$(".arrowRight").click(function() {
  var e = $('.myList');
  var scrollLength = 20;
  e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() + scrollLength);
  if (e.scrollLeft() + e.outerWidth() == e[0].scrollWidth) {
    $('.listItem').first().insertAfter($('.listItem').last());
    e.scrollLeft(e.scrollLeft() + scrollLength);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.myList {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.arrows {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.listItems {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="arrows arrowLeft">&larr;</div>
    
      <div class="myList">
        <div class="listItem">Item 1</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 2</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 3</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 4</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 5</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="arrows arrowRight">&rarr;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. This isn't the solution I've searched. The idea is, when I click the right arrow and click it until I get to the end and than click advance, it should show me the "Item 1" and so on in circle. The same for left: When I get to the end and click advance, it should show me "Item 5" and so on. Like in a circle...

Comment: Please check updated answer ;) Hopefully this is what you want.

Comment: Hello, this is the solution I looked for, thanks! :)